# SSIS - Load data from multiple text files into a single table with parallel processing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, parallel-processing

We have over 1000 flatfiles each with around a million records. We need to insert all this data into a single table on a database and the table cannot be partitioned. We are trying to achieve parallel processing using SSIS by which we want to run muliple bulk insert processes using SSIS to insert data from the flatfiles into the one table simultaneously. Order of inserts from flat files doesnt matter as well. 
We have an SSIS package with a MULTIPLEFLATFILE connection manager with a flatfile task and an OLE DB destination task with 'Fast load' and table lock option checked. With this we see that only one SPID works on inserting data into the table. We would like to have atleast 5 SPIDs/processes insert simultaneously/parallel into the table. Please assist me in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: How long does it take now, and how fast do you need/want it to be?  I ask because there is a very real tradeoff in this case between complexity/effort/cost and the return you can get in terms of speed.

Comment: Currently its taking 5-6 hrs to do the load, but the problem is there is only one bulk insert SPID that i see working on the DB. I want to setup the package so that i can do concurrent inserts into the database. Addl the server is not even near its peak and has 16 processors with 64gb memory. With concurrent/parallel inserts, we would like to reduce the insert time to a few hrs

Answer (score 0):

To get maximum performance for an insert, you'd want to use an OLE DB Destination and there and specify the Fast Load option (in the drop down) and then check Table Lock. This will get the data into the table the fastest. However, you're now going to be forced into serial loads.

To get parallel loads running, you'd need to have each thread loading to its own table and then have an execute sql task at the end merge all the data into the final destination. Essentially the same logic behind merging partitions except instead of simple metadata operations, you'll be moving the data twice.

Comment: is there any way, we can acomplish parallel load without having seperate threads load into seperate tables like the merge option you mentioned above

Comment: I think this is the best option.  However, you may be able to accomplish the parallel bulk loading if the table is a heap with no indexes.  In that scenario, SQL Server does not care what order the rows arrive.  If you have any indexes, SQL Server will require more controls on the order rows arrive because it has to update the indexes as data comes in, even if it arrives in the order of the index.